# A characteristic subgroup is a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, automorphism-group

$\phi(H) = H$ for $\phi$ any automorphism in $G$.

I tried to find a homomorphism for which $H$ is the kernel, which shows that $H$ is normal. However, I tried to have it maps $g$ to $\phi(gH) = \phi(g)H$, but cannot show it preserves the operation because we don't know that $\phi(a)\phi(b) = \phi(a)H\phi(b)H = \phi(a)\phi(b)H$ as we don't have $H$ is normal.

Is this the right way to go? Or should I try something else?

Comment: Hint: https://planetmath.org/innerautomorphism

Comment: The subgroups $H$ that satisfy your hypothesis are called [characteristic subgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup), and the condition is more restrictive than being a normal subgroup. Using $\phi$ to define a homomorphism is not a good idea because $\phi$ stands for _any_ automorphism, not any one of them in particular. In fact the idea of defining a homomorphism, though it can be done, is not very helpful here: justifying that whatever you define is a homomorphism will probably amount to proving that $H$ normal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

let $\phi$ be inner automorphism for example $\phi_g(x)=g^{-1}xg$ for any $g\in G$. Now you can apply this automorphism.

$\phi_g(H)=H$ $\Longrightarrow$ for any $h\in H$ then we have $\phi_g(h)\in H$. Hence $H^g=H$ for any $g\in G$. So $H\trianglelefteq G$.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what $H^g$ means, may you clear it for me? Thanks.

Comment: @AriRoyce:  I'm not sure what it meant, but it's enough to know $g^{-1}Hg = H$ for every  $g\in G $.  In other words normal subgroups are those fixed by *inner* automorphisms while characteristic subgroups are those fixed by *all* automorphisms.

Comment: @hardmath yes, just curious about that notation. Think ever read somewhere, but cannot find it again :)

Comment: @AriRoyce: For a single use the notation doesn't seem to have much value.  In a setting where one discusses (for example) a group's action on its subsets by conjugation, this might be a helpful abbreviation.

Comment: @AriRoyce I think the notation $H^g$ just means the conjugate of $H$ by $g$, i.e. $g^{-1}Hg$

Answer (score 3):

$\phi (H)=H$ for all automorphism 

We wanted to show that H is normal subgroup that is for every $x \in G$ $xHx^{-1}=H$ Now as we have $\phi_x(g)=xgx^{-1}$ as inner automorphism .$\phi_x(H)=xHx^{-1}=H$ Hence Done